# what are NCFB and NOFB modes for?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I can't find it anywhere, when I google it it shows this question posted here. Given that situation I want to ask precisely: What this "n" before cfb and ofb means ?

Comment: Could you please add a little more context to your question?

Comment: These modes are used in mcrypt in php but are not explained in documentation there. (Look at tags)

Comment: Don't use those for new protocols. These modes were considered for noisy communication channels. There are better and certainly more efficient ways of dealing with noisy lines. Note that CFB-8 is n times less efficient than CFB-n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one reference to nCFB and nOFB that I could find:

> Note that CFB and OFB in the rest of the document represent the "8bit CFB or OFB" mode. nOFB and nCFB modes represents a n-bit OFB/CFB mode, **n is used to represent the algorithm's block size**.
>
> ...
>
> nOFB: The Output-Feedback Mode (in nbit). n Is the size of the block of the algorithm. This is a synchronous stream cipher implemented from a block cipher. It is intended for use in noisy lines, because corrupted ciphertext blocks do not corrupt the plaintext blocks that follow. This mode operates in streams.
>
> nCFB: The Cipher-Feedback Mode (in nbit). n Is the size of the block of the algorithm. This is a self synchronizing stream cipher implemented from a block cipher. This mode operates in streams.

http://mcrypt.hellug.gr/lib/mcrypt.3.html

Comment: given that : mcrypt_get_iv_size($cript_alg,'8cfb') - should give a result but it throws error instead

Comment: ok, I gave up, I will use CTR mode from now on, since modes that require padding are less secure. I will accept the answer above for keeping my accept-rate high.

Comment: [PHP appears to use libmcrypt](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c?revision=321634&view=markup). My reading of the quote is that for AES, "nOFB" means 128-bit OFB and "OFB" means 8-bit OFB (note that reduced-bit OFB is considered insecure!). Modes that require padding are not *inherently* less secure, but CTR is decent provided you never reuse an IV/input block (OTOH, the consequences of IV reuse are much more severe than with CBC).

Comment: Actually, it seems that [8-bit OFB mode is secure after all](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25076/is-mcrypts-8-bit-ofb-mode-secure), at least if the IVs are chosen randomly (same as for CFB mode). That said, full-block "nOFB" mode is faster and just as secure (or slightly more so), so there's still no reason to actually use 8-bit OFB.