# What is the Java equivalent of mcrypt "ncfb" mode?

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, mcrypt

I'm trying to port some code from PHP to java and this line is giving me trouble:

```
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $encrypted, "ncfb", $iv);
```

Looking through the javadocs on ciphers there is no 'ncfb' listed, is one of the other modes listed ncfb in disguise?

Comment: I guess that the mode (ncfb, cfb, etc..) does not affect the result.

Comment: Sun JCE doesn't provide Blowfish, so there is no equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574245/what-are-ncfb-and-nofb-modes-for):

> Note that CFB and OFB in the rest of the document represent the "8bit CFB or OFB" mode. nOFB and nCFB modes represents a n-bit OFB/CFB mode, n is used to represent the algorithm's block size.
>
> nCFB: The Cipher-Feedback Mode (in nbit). n Is the size of the block of the algorithm. This is a self synchronizing stream cipher implemented from a block cipher. This mode operates in streams.

Based on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) doc there are following modes (nCFB) available for Blowfish in Java:

> CFB8..CFB64

So the answer would be: yes, there are modes equivalent to nCFB in disguise.